# Using Azure AD for SharePoint Server Authentication, how to handle multiple web applications?

Tags: authentication, azure-ad

I am following the guide [Using Azure AD for SharePoint Server Authentication](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/using-azure-ad-for-sharepoint-server-authentication).  I have it set up and working however I can only specify one Reply URL thus I can only get it set up against one web application.  Using `Set-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $objectid -ReplyUrls $replyUrls` gives me the error:

> Set-AzureADServicePrincipal : Error occurred while executing SetServicePrincipal
>   Code: Request_BadRequest
>   Message: One or more properties on the service principal does not match the application object.

I've tried setting `$replyUrls` as a simple array and as a `System.Collections.Generic.List[String]`.  Setting `$replyURLs` to any value other than what already exists throws the error.  I am also unable to set a wildcard in the Reply URL textbox on the 'Single Sign-on' page nor set an array of values as the site requires a value URL.

How can you configure Azure AD to authenticate against multiple Web Applications?